# Can't get LEFT OUTER JOIN to work through an intersect table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 lookup and 1 intersect tables like:

```
thing                  thing_feature                    feature
+----+-------------+   +----+----------+------------+   +----+-------------+
| id | name        |   | id | thing_id | feature_id |   | id | name        |
+----+-------------+   +----+----------+------------+   +----+-------------+
|  1 | Thing One   |   |  1 |        1 |          1 |   |  1 | Feature A   |
|  2 | Thing Two   |   |  2 |        2 |          1 |   |  2 | Feature B   |
|  3 | Thing Three |   |  3 |        2 |          2 |   |  3 | Feature C   |
|  4 | Thing Four  |   |  4 |        3 |          3 |   |  4 | Feature D   |
+----+-------------+   +----+----------+------------+   +----+-------------+
```

I can't figure out the query to produce...

```
"Thing One", "Feature A"
"Thing Two", "Feature A"
"Thing Two", "Feature B"
"Thing Three", "Feature C"
"Thing Four", null
```

I can get it to include "Thing 4" if I stop at the intersect table...

```
select
  thing.name,
  tf.id
from
  thing
  left outer join thing_feature tf on thing.id = tf.thing_id;

"Thing One", 1
"Thing Two", 1
"Thing Two", 2
"Thing Three", 3
"Thing Four", null
```

...but I can't figure out the syntax to get the query to "join back up" to the feature table through thing_feature.feature_id.  The query I almost have working loses the Feature-less "Thing Four".

```
select
  thing.id,
  thing.name,
  tf.id,
  feature.name
from
  thing
  left outer join thing_feature tf on thing.id = tf.thing_id,
  feature
where
  tf.feature_id = feature.id;

"Thing One", 1, "Feature 1"
"Thing Two", 1, "Feature 1"
"Thing Two", 2, "Feature 2"
"Thing Three", 3, "Feature 3"
```

Perhaps I've been deep in NoSQL for too long.  This is MySQL, if it matters.

Little help here?  What do I need to do to my query to include the "Thing Four" row?

Comment: Why do you have the "Id" field in the thing_feature table?

Comment: @Kevin a design decision made before my time.  All tables have an id field.  It is always marked as the Primary Key.  Its value is auto-generated.  I'm sure the pattern has some name but I don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *almost* there. You just need to do one more left outer join, to make sure you keep all your results on the left tables, and get all the nulls on the right.

```
select
  thing.name,
  f.name
from
  thing
  left outer join thing_feature tf on thing.id = tf.thing_id
  left outer join feature f on tf.feature_id = f.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    t.name tname, t.id, f.name as fname, f.id, tf.tid, tf.feature_id
FROM 
    thing as t
LEFT JOIN
    thing_feature as tf
ON
  t.id = tf.thing_id 
LEFT JOIN
  feature as f
ON 
  tf.feature_id = f.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query-

```
SELECT th.name, ft.name 
FROM thing AS th 
LEFT JOIN thing_feature AS tf ON th.id=tf.thing_id 
LEFT JOIN feature AS ft ON ft.id=tf.feature_id
```

It will first fetch all rows from left table means thing table, then update corresponding rows from right tables, if there is no corresponding value in right side table then it will put NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think by using a RIGHT OUTER JOIN on to the feature table instead, should solve your issue and include the null.